# What does $\partial L$ in $\int _{\partial L}\:xy\:dx\:+\:z\:dy\:+\:\left(x+2y^3\right)dz\:$ mean?

Tags: integration, plane-curves, vector-fields

Let the solid L be given by,

$L=\left\{\left(x,y,z\right)\in R^3∣\:0\le \:z\le \:1-x^2-y^2,\:y\ge \:-x\right\}$

Observe that this solid is limited by the plane $z=0$, the plane $y=-x$ and the paraboloid $z=1-x^2-y^2$.

Let the $F(x,y,z)=(xy,z,x+2y^3)^T$

c) Let $ω$ be the differential form $ω=xy$ $dx$ $+$ $z$ $dy$ $+$ $(x+2y^3)$ $dz$

Calculate $\int _{\partial L}ω.\:$

Comment: It means the boundary of the region $L$.

Comment: But what does the boundary of a solid mean? Is it curves of the solid, or is it the surface of the solid? Could you specify the boundaries for this question?

Comment: @XanderHenderson

Comment: Ah... I did not understand what you were asking.  The boundary of a solid is the surface of the solid.  For example, the boundary of  a solid cube consists of the 6 faces of the cube, or the boundary of a solid ball is a sphere.  In this case, it looks like the boundary consists of two bounded planar regions, and a chunk of the surface of a paraboloid.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks for answering. Then I wonder: As of my understanding this is a setup of a line integral over a vector field? How can that be?

Comment: It isn't a line integral---it is a surface integral.

Comment: I don't understand that. How can $\int _TF\cdot n\:dS\:=\:\int _{\partial L}\:\:ω.\:$? The exercise b) asked me to solve for the flux of all of L. Doesn't that make them completely equal?

Comment: @XanderHenderson

Comment: Am I missing something? $\omega$ looks like a 1-form, so you can't integrate it over the surface $\partial L$. And what does $F$ have to do with anything? You define it and then never use it.

Comment: @user3658307 There is two more parts to this exercise, a) and b) which I didn't write because they unrelated to c). $F$ is included because I wanted to provide all of the exercise description.  If you pay close attention to $ω$ you can see it contains the vector field. I am also unsure how you integrate this and I would love an explanation.

Comment: @DavidLund Look at ths example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Example The integral you must find can be calculated by a triple integral of the divergence of the field. Something like $\int _0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\int _0^{-x}\int _0^{-x^2-y^2+1}\;y\;dzdydx$ which gives, if I did no mistakes $\frac{11}{240 \sqrt{2}}$ Notice that $y$ is the divergence of the field

Comment: @Raffaele Let me just mention a) and b) of the exercise as well. a) asks me to calculate the flux of the surface given by the paraboloid only. b) asks me to calculate the flux out of all of $L$. I used the divergence theorem almost like you did in the exercise b), so how is c) any different from b) then? Or did I do b) wrong?